# I having error locating an element using Xpath

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver, protractor

Having the below html. 
I want to select a particular element using xpath

```
<tbody>
    <tr role="row" id="gridview-1034-record-ext-record-1" data-boundview="gridview-1034" data-recordid="ext-record-1" data-recordindex="0" class="x-grid-row x-grid-data-row x-grid-row-selected x-grid-row-focused" tabindex="-1">
        <td role="gridcell" class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1010 x-grid-cell-first x-unselectable " id="ext-gen1139">
        <div unselectable="on" class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align:left;">03 Oct 2018</div>
        </td>
        <td role="gridcell" class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1013 x-unselectable " id="ext-gen1140">
        <div unselectable="on" class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align:left;">Sales Quotation</div>
        </td>
        <td role="gridcell" class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1016 x-unselectable " id="ext-gen1141">
        <div unselectable="on" class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align:left;">000079</div>
        </td><td role="gridcell" class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1019 x-unselectable " id="ext-gen1142">
        <div unselectable="on" class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align:left;">ABC Bearings Ltd.</div>
        </td><td role="gridcell" class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1022 x-unselectable " id="ext-gen1143">
        <div unselectable="on" class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align:left;">&nbsp;</div></td><td role="gridcell" class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1025 x-unselectable " id="ext-gen1144"><div unselectable="on" class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align:right;">8,000.00</div>
        </td><td role="gridcell" class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1028 x-unselectable " id="ext-gen1145">
        <div unselectable="on" class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align:left;">No</div></td>
        <td role="gridcell" class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1031 x-grid-cell-last x-unselectable " id="ext-gen1146">
        <div unselectable="on" class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align:left;">Approved</div>
        </td>
        </tr>
</tbody>
```

I am unable to locate the below element and click it using XPath using the below code.

Help would be much appreciated

```
element(by.xpath('//tbody/tr/td/div')).click();
                    expect(div.getText()).toBe('000079');
```

Comment: please provide more information as mock html, error, goal.

Comment: Your html example starts with tr, but your xpath starts with tbody ... please complete your example.

Comment: There is <tbody> </tbody> and i am unable to click the row i also tried this  element(by.id('gridview-1034-record-ext-record-2')).click();

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/3021395/powerstat ??

Comment: Your problem is that the xpath normally would result in multiple elements as result - so in your case the first one might be picket but not the one you want. You need to be more precise in your xpath like with adding a [3] for the third node to pick.

Comment: actually what i want is i want to select the <tr> which is behaving as a single Row i did it using id for that ID but it is not selecting

Comment: @Rao , try to remove `tbody` from your XPath. Also try to wait some time for table to be rendered

Comment: @Andersson u mean this browser.driver.sleep(time);

Comment: @Rao No, I mean [this](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits)

Comment: @Andersson using my line of code of Xpath it says no Div defined

Comment: @Andersson thanks wait for rendering works

Answer (score 0):

You can use `contains(text(),'...')` for matching the div you want and then click it.

```
element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tbody/tr/td/div[contains(text(), 'div text you want')]"));
element.click()
```

Comment: have you tried
element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(), 'div text you want')]"));
this ?

Answer (score 0):

To locate the element with text as **000079** you can use the following solution:

- *XPath*:

  ```
  //td[starts-with(@id,'ext-gen')]/div[@class='x-grid-cell-inner' and contains(.,'000079')]
  ```
- Line of code:

  ```
  element(by.xpath("//td[starts-with(@id,'ext-gen')]/div[@class='x-grid-cell-inner' and contains(.,'000079')]")).click();
  ```

Comment: can explain little more how to use your solutino

Comment: Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status

Comment: element.all(by.cssContainingText('[class*="x-grid-row x-grid-row-alt x-grid-data-row x-grid-row-selected x-grid-row-focused x-grid-row-over"]','')).click();  i did tried this too but it did not worked

Comment: You asked about _XPath_, so my answer is based on _XPath_, update the question with the error you see with my answer

Comment: i have used many alternative to select that row but i found none to be worked for me plz help...

Answer (score 0):

I agree with answer from @Faisal Maqbool. I would shorten the xpath a bit as follows,

`element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(), 'div text you want')]"));`
`element.click();`

You want to try and select the exact element directly if you can, complicate the xpath only if you can find no other option.

Answer (score 0):

Element with text '000079' is present on tr[1]td[3]. You can use the following solution:

```
 WebElement e1= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/div[1]"));
    String Str=e1..getText();
    if(Str="000079")
    { System.out.println("Text matched"+Str);
e1.click();
    }
    else
    {
    System.out.println("Text Mismatched"+Str);
    }
```

Comment: var e1= element(By.xpath("//tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/div[1]"));
      var Str=e1.getText();
      if(Str="000079")
      {e1.click();
      }
      else
      {
      System.out.println("Text Mismatched"+Str);
      }

Comment: it says element is not intractable

Comment: Ae you sure that element is interactable? Can you please print element text when if the condition is satisfied. Please refer above code. If System.out.println("Text matched"+Str); is printing 000079 then you are able to find your element from DOM.

Comment: firstly im using protractor not Selenium with java

Comment: it gives me output for str == 000079 on console followed by more than 1 element found for locator

Answer (score 0):

```
String Str = "000079";
            List<WebElement> listEle = driver.findElements(By.Xpath("Your Xpath"));
            System.out.println("List Printer " + listEle);
            Iterator<WebElement> iter = listEle.iterator();
            System.out.println("Iterator Print" + iter);
            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                WebElement we = iter.next();
                System.out.println("Web Element We " + we.getText());
                if (we.getText().equals(str)) {
                    we.click();
                }
            }
```